# How to stop vusers in middle of the test execution in loadrunner controller

Tags: loadrunner

In load runner controller I am running the test with 10 virtual users, 10 users are doing their tasks.

How to stop 5 vusers during the test execution?

Answer (score 3):

- Go to run screen
- Then go-to groups
- click on running vuser a small window will popup now select no of vuser you want to stop and click on ok.

Answer (score 0):

highlight them and hit the stop button.  This will stop them at the end of the current step